# Video not playing in mac

Tags: video, codec, h.264, mac

I use a OnePlus 6 mobile for recording videos and so far I have never transferred the video to my Macbook Pro, however, I recently copied all my videos to learn video editing.

All videos play smoothly in the mobile, but whichever the video I copied from my mobile aren't playing smoothly in the laptop.

Videos are recorded in H.264 format in 1080p. One strange difference I noticed was that all the videos recorded using the front camera, plays smoothly, but the rear camera does not. Also, 720p content from just works fine.

I'm having hard time understanding what is the problem. Please help. I'm sure if the problem is with the mobile phone or the codecs which are installed in my Macbook Pro.

I've tried using Quicktime player, VLC Player and DaVinci Resolve.

Comment: Have you tried to encode it again using ffmpeg or handbrake? It might just be a codec / container problem

Comment: Yes, I tried with Handbrake, but no luck. In fact, handbrake creates a file in KB while my actually video is hundreds of MB and the new encoded video is useless.

Comment: That seems very strange.. It might be that your file is corrupt, can you send over the original clip?